# Is there any way to fetch default broser's cache in webview?

Tags: android, caching, android-webview

I have open my phone's default browser and open http://stackoverflow.com url. I have perform proper login steps there and I am easily be able to view my profile in default browser.

Now, I have created an Webview application which loads "http://stackoverflow.com" url but in my Webview but it is not showing me as logged in mode. Obviously it is not fetching cache details from default browser.

Now my question is, How can I fetch my login details in Webview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I fetch my login details in Webview ?

In general, you don't. You do not have rights to steal information from other apps, any more than they have the right to steal information from yours.

If, however, you "perform proper login steps" inside of the `WebView`, you will be logged in within that `WebView`.

If your end objective is to use [the StackExchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/), you should be able to use [their OAuth 2.0 authentication system](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).

Comment: when I click on login link in webview, my application loads the default browser, and using StackExchange's API I have already perform the login programmatically successfully.

Comment: @Vigbyor: "when I click on login link in webview, my application loads the default browser" -- most likely, that is being caused by the server issuing a redirect. If you want to show the redirected Web page in the `WebView`, instead of the default browser, you need to use a `WebViewClient` subclass and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`.

Comment: Ok, I will try and let you know if I need further help, Thank You.